# Making a query by different columns with the same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to make a query in Rails **4** where I want to filter to 2 different columns or fields by "OR". How can I do that? I only know how to query using one fields and different values.

```
MyModel.where(my_field: ["var1", "var2"])
```

But I want to use different columns and the same value and "OR".

Comment: has your question been resolved?

Comment: Awesome. If it was resolved by one of the answers below, then please accept one. Otherwise, please provide your own answer and accept that.

Comment: @jeffdill2, man, why are you so obsessed about that? I don't think it's needed to accept one.

Comment: This is a community - treat it as such. 1.) By accepting or providing/accepting an answer, this question will stop showing up in the "unanswered" queue, which means everybody doesn't have to keep wasting their time looking over questions that actually already have answers, 2.) often times, even the answerer is not sure their answer will work because they're trying to help you solve an issue they've never dealt with before, so you're acceptance actually helps *the answerer* to learn because you're validating their attempt, ...

Comment: 3.) by providing your own answer (if none of the provided answers work for you), you're helping the community to learn because if they experience a similar problem, they can see how you solved it and *everybody benefits*, 4.) contributing to other users' reputation also helps the community because you're getting them to higher privileges - for newer users, you help get them to where they can vote, flag, comment, etc. - for more seasoned users, you help them get access to review queues, privileges for editing, etc. - again, *everybody benefits*, ...

Comment: 5.) and is it required? No. But a community is about give and take - if you establish yourself as *only* a taker, nobody's going to want to help you with your questions anymore. I'd be curious to know what you're reasoning would be to *not* accept or provide a correct answer.

Comment: @jeffdill2, you're fun.

Comment: there it is. Glad I could help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about doing something like this:

```
MyModel.where("my_field=? OR my_second_field=?", 'test', 'test')
```

*Also for reference see section 2.2 Array Conditions:* 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: @jawanam updated the answer, but the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you:

```
MyModel.where(
 {some_field: "value"} | 
 {some_other_field: "value"}
)
```

String interpolation, as mentioned in Bryan's answer, is also perfectly valid. However, this is my preferred method for a couple of reasons:

1. It's very readable.
2. It's easy and clean to add more fields, if you decide you need to search for a particular value across 4 fields instead of 2, while still maintaining readability.